# how to join two files based on their second column without changing the order of non of columns of the first file?

Tags: join, awk, merge

FOR example here are two data files:

file1:

```
        target
     1 6791340 10.9213
     2  6934561 9.6791
     3  6766224 9.5835
     4  6753444 9.1097
     5  6809077 8.7386
     6  6818752 8.7172
```

fil2:

```
1 6766224 11.7845
2 6753444 9.6863
3 6809077 9.5252
4 6818752 9.3867
5 6791340 9.1914
6 6934561 9.1914
```

file3(output):

```
     target
 1  6791340 10.9213 5 9.1914 
 2  6934561 9.6791  6 9.1914
 3  6766224 9.5835  1 11.7845
 4  6753444 9.1097  2 9.6863
 5  6809077 8.7386  3 9.5252
 6  6818752 8.7172  4 9.3867
```

As you can see, the order of target column stayed exactly the same as file1. But, file2 follows the order of file1 based on target column and columns from file2 changed accordingly. the real files are big and "target" is written just for clarification. any guide, please?

This is what I tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2]=$1; next }{ print a[$1],$1,$2 }' file1 file2 > 
output
```

But this changes the order of target column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the easiest way not to sort the two files on column two and then sort again on column 1? Be aware that you do buffer here and call various programs. A clean `awk` solution is given by [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297358/8344060).

```
 % join -j2 <(sort -g -k2 file1) <(sort -g -k2 file2) \
        -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.3 | sort -g -k1   
1 6791340 10.9213 5 9.1914
2 6934561 9.6791 6 9.1914
3 6766224 9.5835 1 11.7845
4 6753444 9.1097 2 9.6863
5 6809077 8.7386 3 9.5252
6 6818752 8.7172 4 9.3867
```

The flag `-o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.3` is the output option of `join`, it dictates to print column 1 of file 1 (`1.1`), followed by column 2 of file 1 (`1.2`), etc.

> **`man join`** :
>   `-o FORMAT`
>                 obey `FORMAT` while constructing output line
>
> `FORMAT` is one or more comma or blank separated specifications, each
>          being `FILENUM.FIELD` or `0`.  Default `FORMAT` outputs the join field, the remaining fields from FILE1, the remaining fields from
>   FILE2, all separated by CHAR.  If `FORMAT` is the keyword `auto`, then
>   the first line of each  file
>          determines the number of fields output for each line.

Without this option, you would still have to swap column 1 and 2.

```
join -j2 <(sort -g -k2 file1) <(sort -g -k2 file2) | awk '{t=$2;$2=$1;$1=t}1' | sort -g -k1
```

Comment: @zara be aware that this solution (and the one of Sundeep) only work if column 2 has unique numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Switch the order of file processing

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1 OFS $3; next} ($2 in a){print $0, a[$2]}' f2 f1
1 6791340 10.9213 5 9.1914
2 6934561 9.6791 6 9.1914
3 6766224 9.5835 1 11.7845
4 6753444 9.1097 2 9.6863
5 6809077 8.7386 3 9.5252
6 6818752 8.7172 4 9.3867
```

- `($2 in a)` can be removed if both second columns will surely match